How to restore Home category prestashop without database access?
I deleted Home category prestashop by mistake,
my problem is that I don't have access to the database,
how to restore it without database access please? thank you
I tried to import with csv file and set ID to 2 but it doesn't work

You can try to use Database -> Manager SQL inside prestashop BO and generate SQL for add category

Thank you for response but Only Select is allow in manager sql
